# ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE when posting with jquery to localhost django server

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, google-chrome-extension

I have a **chrome extension** and I want it to make an ajax call to my localhost development server (Django).

So the **js** looks like :

```
$('#create_profile_form').submit(function(e){
        var pseudo = $("#create_pseudo_input").val()
        var email = $("#create_email_input").val()
        console.log(pseudo)
        $.post({
            url:'https://localhost:8000/test_ajax/',
            data:{
                'pseudo': pseudo,
                'email': email,
            },
            success:function(){
                alert("trop coule")
            }
        }).fail(function(){
            alert('ERROR')
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and the **python** script:

```
def test_ajax(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "received {0} {1}".format(
            request.POST['email'], request.POST['pseudo'])
    else:
        message = "error -> no ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

The server runs with **[django-sslserver](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver)**

When I submit the form I get `POST https://localhost:8000/test_ajax/ net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` in the Chrome console.

What should I do:

1/ to make development easy

2/ to ensure future production security

Comment: 1. Typo: `'psuedo'` 2. It takes just a few seconds to find at least several answers just by googling `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` - is there a reason those don't suit you?

Comment: @wOxxOm I have gone through these and I'm lost. The error means the browser does not trust localhost:8000 to be who it claims to be. How do I tell chrome "it's ok for this one"?

Comment: I guess generate a different certificate using a different toolchain, https://crbug.com/574333 says genkey is ok, openssl isn't.